# An infinite number of non-isomorphic groups

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find a set of groups such that no two are isomorphic. I was recommended to consider the set of symmetric groups, i.e.
$A = \{S_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}.$ After playing around with the symmetric
groups, I came across the fact that no two groups seem to be isomorphic, and
thus I would like to prove the statement that $S_n$ is isomorphic to $S_m$ if
and only if $n = m.$

Note by the structure of the permutations groups that $o(S_n) = n! \wedge
o(S_m) = m!$. I understand that if $n = m$, every group is isomorphic to itself
and thus $S_n$ is isomorphic to $S_n = S_m$ in this case. However, I am having
some difficulty proving it the other way around. Any recommendations?

Comment: An isomorphism of groups is also a bijection, so if two groups have different orders then they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: Cyclic groups of different orders is an obvious solution.

Comment: the subgroups of $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any isomorphism needs to also be bijective and the only way you can have a bijection between two finite sets is if those two sets have the same number of elements. Thus, since $n \neq m \implies |S_n| \neq |S_m|$ then $S_n$ and $S_m$ are not isomorphic when $n \neq m$.